# How to resize UIContainerView to fit embedded UITableView?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, uistoryboard, uicontainerview

SO...

I have two UIContainerViews on one ViewController in my Storyboard. The problem I'm facing is both TableViews have separate, dynamic datasources. When they load, each tableview's contentSize is larger than the parent UIContainerView.

This means each tableView will scroll independently from each other, without touching the parent ViewController's scrollview. Both ContainerViews are embedded on a parent scrollview.

What I'm looking to do is return the height of each UITableView, set the corresponding ContainerView's height, and set the contentSize of the parent scrollview so everything scrolls together as one. Effectively making one long UITableView, made up of two UITableViews.

Is this the correct way of doing this? If not, is there a better way to have two tableviews on one viewcontroller? Any and all help is appreciated.

(Any clarifications are fully warranted)

Comment: Get the height of each of your cells and the number of cells in the table view, and you'll have the total height for the table. Then just change the frame of your table.

Comment: Hey pablo, appreciate your response. The main thing is these cells are all dynamic sizes based on the content being loaded, So I will need to determine the tableview content size after all the cells have loaded, then return that value to the parent view for resizing. It's a head scratcher...

Comment: That's fine, just get the height of every single cell in `- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;`, so just after `[self.tableView reloadData];` set the frame of the table. Hope this helps